# JavaFX ButtonSkin anomaly

Tags: button, slider, javafx

In the following code, why isn't the button text initially displayed when ButtonSkin (from com.sun.javafx.scene.control.caspian) is used?

In the following code (running WinXP, NetBeans 6.7.1, JavaFX 1.2 , JDK 1.6), when ButtonSkin is used, the button text starts as blank.   After the slider is used, te button text is displayed.

[image: alt txt]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://onecynic.googlepages.com/withButtonSkin.jpg))</sub>
 to [image]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://onecynic.googlepages.com/withButtonSkinAfterAdjust.jpg))</sub>

If you press the button before moving the slider, the action is triggered, printing "Some action slider 15.0 SliderInt 15".  That suggests the information for the button text is present.   Yet the button text is not displayed.

If the skin isn't set, that is, the code    `skin: ButtonSkin { ... }`  is commented out, on start-up the result is:

[image: alt txt]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://onecynic.googlepages.com/withoutButtonSkin.jpg))</sub>

If one instead removes the bind in the  `text: sliderIntText` , the problem also goes away.  However, the button text is no longer updated in sync with the slider movement.

Removing the levels of indirection, i.e., just binding to answerSlider.value in the button text makes no change in the start-up issue.

Aside:  There is a known slider value problem which occurs when the slider min is not 0.  I'm not trying to resolve that issue here.

```
package skinbutton;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.caspian.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

    var answerSlider =
            Slider {
              min: 6
              max: 32
              value: 15

              width: 100
              translateX: 75
              translateY: 20
           };

  var sliderIntValue:Integer =  bind (java.lang.Math.floor(answerSlider.value)) as Integer ;
  var sliderIntText = bind "SliderInt {%d sliderIntValue}";

   var sceneSlider = Scene{
        content: [
            answerSlider,
            Text {
              font : Font {
                 size: 14
              }
              x: 75
              y: 50
              content: bind "Slider at {%4.1f answerSlider.value}"
           }
           Button {
              translateX: 75
              translateY: 60
              skin:    ButtonSkin {
                    fill: Color.LIGHTCORAL
                    textFill: Color.BLACK
             }
              text: bind sliderIntText
              width: 95
              font: Font.font("SansSerif", FontWeight.BOLD, 14)
              action: function() {
                   println("Some action slider {%4.1f answerSlider.value} {sliderIntText}");
              }
           }
           ]
        };

Stage {
    title: "Button Skin Issue"
    width: 250
    height: 130
    scene: sceneSlider
}
```

Comment: wow .. is this old ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't have a specific answer to this issue, but I do know that the new controls in 1.2 are rather buggy - so it doesn't surprise me that you are seeing problems such as this.

If you haven't already done so, I'd encourage you to raise a defect under the 'runtime' section on the Javafx JIRA site at: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I was hoping that there was a coding problem/oversight on my part.    Per your suggestion, I have created an issue: RT-5386 (which I apparently do not have permission to view).

Comment: Yes - it is really annoying but you have to email the administrator of the module you added the defect to (eg Runtime), and ask them to give you permission.

Comment: Message sent on Tuesday (Aug 18) to Runtime project lead about getting access.